# How to write the url to a LAN SVN repository?

Tags: svn

As I know, I can create a SVN repository on my local machine, and visit it with the URL:"file://localhost/C:/repos/trunk/pro1", but my question is if I want to let others who are also on the same LAN to visit, how can I finish it. I mean I don't want to set up a SubVersion server, because I just want to share codes with only another guy, how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to setup Subversion server, but you **must** to do it, if you want to have repository accessible outside local host

Comment: yeah, you're right. Although I can using share folder to solve this, it is not recommend at all. It seems I have to setup a server for sharing codes with others, even only one other guy.

Comment: @jason - svnserve'd repo is **really easy and fast** way